# Python self referencing for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
for a[-1] in a:
    print(a[-1])
```

The output is `0 1 2 2`

Why does `a[-1]` change with each iteration?

Comment: Because you told it to by using that as the iteration variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are the changing `a[-1]` value while iterating. The iterating variable is a reference to objects in the iterable.

```
lst = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

#    ---> Iterating variable
#    |
for val in lst:
    val.append(55)
print(lst)
# [[1, 2, 55], [3, 4, 55]]
```

Because `a` is a reference to objects you're iterating over.

In your case, your iterating variable is `a[-1]` itself. So, you keep on changing `a[-1]`. You can debug by adding `print(...)` statements here.

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
for a[-1] in a:
    print(a)

[0, 1, 2, 0] # a[-1] == a[0]
[0, 1, 2, 1] # a[-1] == a[1]
[0, 1, 2, 2] # a[-1] == a[2]
[0, 1, 2, 2] # a[-1] == a[3]
```

Answer (score 6):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
a[-1] = a[0]
print(a[-1])

a[-1] = a[1]
print(a[-1])

a[-1] = a[2]
print(a[-1])

a[-1] = a[3]
print(a[-1])
```

Each time through the loop it assigns the value of the current list element to `a[-1]` and then prints it.

Answer (score 0):

The first `a[-1]` (aka a[3]) is a variable that you assign the value you extract from `a`.  In the 2nd to last iteration it sets `a[-1] = a[2]` which is `2`.  In the last iteration you extract `a[3]` which now is now the value `2`.

Answer (score 0):

1. first element of a is 0
2. set a[-1] to that
3. print(a[-1]) so 0
4. second element of a is 1
5. set a[-1] to that
6. print(a[-1]) so 1
7. third element of a is 2
8. set a[-1] to that
9. print(a[-1]) so 2
10. **fourth element is the last one** and you just set it to 2 in 9.
11. set a[-1] to that, *i.e.* to 2 again
12. print(a[-1]) so 2